# PopupWindow, dispatch key event

Tags: android, window

How do I dispatch key events from a focusable PopupWindow to an underlying Activity. If I set the
window as focusable, it consumes all events. I want to be able to intercept a key, and handle
the event.

Here is my dilemma:
My PopupWindow contains a EditText, in order to display the keyboard ontop of the window I'm forced to set the focus on the window. The problem, due to the focus, is that I can't intercept the key event, in this case the menu button, to dismiss the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can only handle event to focused view.

You could try to use my CustomPopUp.

Here how it work: if you click on EditText, type something, then open CustomPopUp and continue typing you will type in EditText. So even when you open CustomPopUp previous view  is focused.

```
public class CustomPopUp extends PopupWindow
{

    private final View.OnTouchListener customPopUpTouchListenr = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event)
        {

            return false;
        }
    };

    public CustomPopUp(final View theView)
    {
        super(theView);

        initView();

        setTouchInterceptor(customPopUpTouchListenr);

    }

    private void initView()
    {
        setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        setTouchable(true);
        setOutsideTouchable(true);

        setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, in this case the EditText view is inside of the window itself. So I have to focus the window inorder to display the keyboard.

Comment: That didn't solve my problem, as I said, the popup requires focus inorder for the edittext inside the popup window to work. I solved the problem by taking the PopupWindow from the Android source and modify the dispatch key method.

Comment: @user634545 would you please provide the code that you used to solve the problem?